# Does the summation property $\sum a_{k} x^{i+k}=x^{i} \sum a_{k} x^{k}$ have a name?

Tags: summation, terminology

Does this particular summation property have a name? **I would like to see a proof for it** but I am having difficulty finding one and I am not sure what to search for.

I came across it in [a document](http://web.vu.lt/mif/e.manstavicius/wp-content/uploads/2017/12/Section.5.2.pdf) describing a listing of "summation facts".

Comment: It's just a special case of $\sum ca_k = c \sum a_k$ which listed in the same document.

Comment: That's just distributivity of multiplication over addition, like $ab+ac=a(b+c)\,$.